# Project Euler #13 in Swift - Large sum

Tags: programming-challenge, swift

I just finished [Project Euler #13](https://projecteuler.net/problem=13) in Swift, and since there is not any version yet on Code Review, I would like to have some comments on what I did to try to improve it.

> Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred
>   50-digit numbers.
>
> 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
>   46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
>   74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
>   91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
>   23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676
>   89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757
>   28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738
>   44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318
>   47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276
>   70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951
>   62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331
>   64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178
>   92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407
>   58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828
>   80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390
>   35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586
>   86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829
>   71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938
>   54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604
>   53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145
>   36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721
>   45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045
>   17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412
>   81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692
>   51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483
>   62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691
>   15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209
>   55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126
>   18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515
>   80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954
>   78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581
>   16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984
>   48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030
>   87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332
>   59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210
>   69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085
>   41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271
>   65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375
>   35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307
>   94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275
>   88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271
>   25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526
>   36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962
>   24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141
>   91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403
>   34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470
>   23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583
>   11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470
>   63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533
>   67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822
>   95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774
>   76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236
>   37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967
>   23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522
>   29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501
>   18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715
>   38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381
>   34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539
>   40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635
>   29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903
>   41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922
>   62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457
>   23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519
>   86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672
>   11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308
>   82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581
>   97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500
>   42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327
>   55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789
>   32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886
>   75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337
>   62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731
>   32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504
>   99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622
>   73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724
>   76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818
>   97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852
>   87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090
>   10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786
>   71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039
>   62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116
>   66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411
>   60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714
>   85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096
>   66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297
>   64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252
>   16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011
>   94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791
>   78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699
>   15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078
>   40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353
>   44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535
>   41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954
>   81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280
>   82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608
>   22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197
>   77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617
>   72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516
>   20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722
>   53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690

```
import Foundation

func addToResult(inout results:[Int], var addResult:Int, index:Int) {

    if index == results.count {
        results.append(0)
    }

    addResult = results[index] + addResult

    var result = addResult % 10

    results[index] = result

    var retain = addResult / 10
    if retain > 0 {
        addToResult(&results, retain, index + 1)
    }
}

func add(left:String, right:String) -> String {

    let leftNumbers:[Int] = Array(left).reverse().map() { String($0).toInt()! }
    let rightNumbers:[Int] = Array(right).reverse().map() { String($0).toInt()! }

    var results:[Int] = [Int]()
    var index = max(leftNumbers.count, rightNumbers.count)

    var i = 0
    while i < index {

        let leftNumber = i >= leftNumbers.count ? 0 : leftNumbers[i]
        let rightNumber = i >= rightNumbers.count ? 0 : rightNumbers[i]

        let addResult = leftNumber + rightNumber
        addToResult(&results, addResult, i)

        i++
    }

    return "".join(results.reverse().map() { String($0) } )
}

func largeSum(numbers:[String]) -> String {

    var result = ""
    for number in numbers {

        result = add(result, number)

    }

    return result
}

func euler13() {
    let numbers = [
        "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250",
        "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538",
        "74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629",
        "91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250",
        "23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676",
        "89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757",
        "28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738",
        "44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318",
        "47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276",
        "70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951",
        "62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331",
        "64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178",
        "92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407",
        "58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828",
        "80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390",
        "35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586",
        "86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829",
        "71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938",
        "54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604",
        "53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145",
        "36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721",
        "45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045",
        "17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412",
        "81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692",
        "51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483",
        "62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691",
        "15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209",
        "55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126",
        "18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515",
        "80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954",
        "78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581",
        "16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984",
        "48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030",
        "87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332",
        "59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210",
        "69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085",
        "41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271",
        "65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375",
        "35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307",
        "94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275",
        "88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271",
        "25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526",
        "36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962",
        "24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141",
        "91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403",
        "34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470",
        "23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583",
        "11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470",
        "63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533",
        "67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822",
        "95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774",
        "76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236",
        "37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967",
        "23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522",
        "29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501",
        "18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715",
        "38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381",
        "34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539",
        "40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635",
        "29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903",
        "41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922",
        "62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457",
        "23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519",
        "86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672",
        "11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308",
        "82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581",
        "97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500",
        "42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327",
        "55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789",
        "32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886",
        "75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337",
        "62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731",
        "32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504",
        "99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622",
        "73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724",
        "76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818",
        "97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852",
        "87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090",
        "10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786",
        "71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039",
        "62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116",
        "66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411",
        "60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714",
        "85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096",
        "66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297",
        "64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252",
        "16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011",
        "94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791",
        "78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699",
        "15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078",
        "40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353",
        "44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535",
        "41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954",
        "81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280",
        "82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608",
        "22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197",
        "77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617",
        "72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516",
        "20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722",
        "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690"
    ]

    let number = largeSum(numbers)

    println(number)
}

func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(operation:() -> ()) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    println("Time elapsed : \(timeElapsed) s")
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(euler13)
```

The code executes in 0.1s

I'm not fan of the `add` function I did. Maybe storing the results in an `[Int]`, was not the best choice, but I do not like the way `String` *ranges/nTh character* are handled.
I did not find an elegant/performant way to have something like this :

```
let str = "123"
str[3] // An Optional Int?
str[2] // 3 as an Int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the numbers array

```
let numbers = [
    "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250",
    ...
    "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690"
]
```

takes a lot of space in the `euler13()` function and therefore distracts from
the relevant code. I would store the original data from the Project Euler problem 
into a text file and load the data from there. That also helps to avoid copy/paste
errors or other typos, e.g. when adding the quotation marks and commas.

For an Xcode command-line project this is done by adding a "Other->Empty" file "data.txt" to the project and adding this file to the "Copy Files" build phase:

[image]

Then you can copy/paste the given data into this file and load it at runtime,
so that the main function becomes

```
func euler13() {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "txt")!
    let data = NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
    let numbers = data.componentsSeparatedByString("\n") as [String]

    let number = largeSum(numbers)
    println(number)
}
```

Strictly speaking, your output is not correct, as the problem asks only for the
first 10 digits of the sum. This would be done with

```
func euler13() {
    // ...

    let number = largeSum(numbers)
    println(number[number.startIndex ..< advance(number.startIndex, 10)])
}
```

Storing the numbers in an integer array is a good choice, as working on a Swift
string directly would most probably be much slower. But I would separate
the `String <-> [Int]` conversions into separate functions:

```
func stringToIntArray(str : String) -> [Int] {
    return Array(str).reverse().map() { String($0).toInt()! }
}

func intArrayToString(num: [Int]) -> String {
    return "".join(num.reverse().map() { String($0) } )
}
```

Your code computes the sum of two "large numbers" in an integer array and
then converts that array back to a string. In the next step the string is
converted to an integer array again for the next addition.

It would be more effective to use only integer arrays for all intermediate
results, and convert only the final sum back to a string.
Then `largeSum()` would look like this:

```
func largeSum(numbers:[String]) -> String {

    var result : [Int] = []
    for number in numbers {
        let num = stringToIntArray1(number)
        addToIntArray(&result, num)
    }

    return intArrayToString(result)
}
```

Your `addToResult` functions adds only a single digit to a "large integer"
(represented as an `[Int]`) array. It is more effective to add two "large integers" in a single loop:

```
func addToIntArray(inout result: [Int], num: [Int]) {
    var carry = 0
    let commonLength = min(result.count, num.count)
    var index = 0
    while index < commonLength {
        let sum = result[index] + num[index] + carry
        result[index] = sum % 10
        carry = sum / 10
        index++
    }
    while index < num.count {
        let sum = num[index] + carry
        result.append(sum % 10)
        carry = sum / 10
        index++
    }
    while index < result.count && carry > 0 {
        let sum = result[index] + carry
        result[index] = sum % 10
        carry = sum / 10
        index++
    }
    if carry > 0 {
        result.append(carry)
    }
}
```

On my computer, these changes reduced the time from 0.032 to 0.017 seconds.

Now profiling showed that much of the time is spent in the `stringToIntArray()`
function. The following version is significantly faster:

```
func stringToIntArray(str : String) -> [Int] {
    var num : [Int] = []
    let unicodeDigitZero = 48

    for digit in str.unicodeScalars {
        num.append(Int(digit.value) - unicodeDigitZero)
    }

    return reverse(num)
}
```

The computation time is now 0.006 seconds.

Ideas for further possible improvements:

- Store more than one decimal digit in each element of the `[Int]` array.
  This would make the addition faster, but the string to array conversion 
  more complicated.
- *Cheat*. The problem asks only for the first 10 digits of the sum.
  That means that only a initial portion of the given numbers is actually needed.

Comment: I changed everything but the `add` function. I just made it add the two large integers into a single loop. It is way faster/cleaner now!
Thanks a lot for the good code reviews! Learning a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your program tremendously. Consider the following two things:

1. You only need to sum the first 11 numbers to get the correct sum
2. Take advantage of Swift's functional aspect

The entire solution can be condensed into this:

```
var totalSum = strings.map({
    $0.substringToIndex(advance($0.startIndex, 11)).toInt()!
}).reduce(0, +)

var stringSum : String = String(totalSum)
var sum = stringSum.substringToIndex(advance(stringSum.startIndex, 10))

println(sum)
```

#### Explanation

We use `array.map()` to create a new array from the existing numbers array. The new array contains the first 11 digits of each number from the original array. Each element is an int, converted using `toInt()`, which lets us apply `reduce()` to sum the array.

We then convert the sum to a string, and take the first 10 chars. And voila, you solved it.

This assumes you already have an array of strings, as is the case in your code:

```
let strings = [
    "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250",
    // ...
    "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690"
]
```

Comment: I did not want to "cheat". I am trying to get the "cleanest" solution possible. If the problem asked for the entire result, this solution would not work. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Mehdi.Sqalli you are welcome. Even if you did not want to cheat, you can use the same code with two modifications: Change the `int` to a `BigInt` equivalent (not sure if Swift supports it out of the box) and remove the substring part. I understand you do not want to take shortcuts, but that's not cheating. It's part of Project Euler: it's expected, and encouraged to find the most efficient solution. For example, some problems, like problem 3, would take years for a computer to solve if you did not take a shortcut.

Comment: There is not any BigInt in swift yet. I totally understand the efficiency part of the Project Euler. I just used this problem to do my own infinite add. Which I had to do anyway for the Problem 16 (Power digit sum).